# How to test against a mixed distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixture-distribution

There is a population $D$ in which each data point has two attributes $X$ and $Y$ that are randomly distributed. While they are probably not exactly normally distributed I imagine they are not too pathological. I don't know their means and $s.d.$'s, but they are likely to be somewhat similar. I also don't know a priori whether $\mu_X$ or $\mu_Y$ is bigger; I also don't know whether $X$ and $Y$ are correlated.

There is another set of data $D'$, with the same two attributes but slightly differently distributed: $X'$ and $Y'$ are distributed $X' \sim X + c1$ and $Y' \sim Y + c2$ where $c1$ and $c2$ are assumed to be constant but unknown.

I can sample directly from $X$ (without knowing $Y$) or from $Y$ (without knowing $X$); and, I can also sample from $max(X', Y')$ in which I can get identifiers that state whether each value comes from $X'$ or $Y'$, i.e., whether $x' > y'$ or $y' > x'$ for this data point. Although the variables are real numbers, because of the sampling procedure they are rounded. As a result, $x'$ and $y'$ can tie and in which case the identifier would report either $X'$ or $Y'$ randomly.

I have two questions. What is the best way to test:

1. whether $X' > X$ and $Y' > Y$?
2. whether $max(X', Y')$ > $max(X, Y)$?

Comment: I think it is critical whether $X$ and $Y$ are dependent or independent. It is not clear from the question. Are they independently distributed?

Comment: Personally I believe that they are positively correlated, but I don't have data yet (I suppose it's possible to change the sampling procedure so that I can find out both $X$ and $Y$ for samples in $D$). If I make that assumption, how can I test for those two hypotheses?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ideas:

If you can sample x and y or max(x,y) then you can compare max(x,y) to max(x',y').  You can use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test since the max values will not be normal, or even a t-test if the sample size is large enough for the CLT to apply.

Another option is to use censored methods.  Since you know max(x',y') and whether you observe x' or y' you have censored data.  If you observe x' then you know that y' is less than x' even though you don't know the value of y'.  There are survival analysis techniques for comparing 2 groups with censored observations that you could use to compare x' to x and then y' to y.  Most survival methods work for right censored observations and you have left censored, but if you multiply everything by $-1$ then you change the right censored to left censored.